# Create java.awt.Image from an array of bytes

Tags: java, android, stream

I am using the below codes to transform the bitmap coming from android device in an array of bytes and sending for a Java SE app via UDP, it is working well, my question is how to transform this byte array to java.awt.Image.

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

In android I could do something like

```
ImageView myImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
myImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytSig, 0, bytSig.length))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(yourByteArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

java.awt.Toolkit.createImage has a byte-array variant.
So that would be:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

byte[] imagedata = ...;
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imagedata);
```